# Can I implement PayPal´s Express Checkout in Argentina?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, express-checkout

this is my question: Can I implement PayPal´s Express Checkout in Argentina?

I was using the sandbox and now I'm trying to go live with my app, but in the "My Apps & Credentials" (PayPal´s developers web) section, where I'm supposed to create the my **live** credentials, got the following error:

```
braintreeCredentials.validCountryLiveTokenError
```

Does this means I can't use Express Checkout in my country? is there any workaround for this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, I had to create my credentials from the paypal account, instead of the developers.paypal dashboard.

When I try it in the "developer" page, I got that error, but in the docs, Argentina is allowed to implement express checkout, so it was weird.

Now works

(I used Laravel 5 and Omnipay)